# Multicore and multithread on Ipython Notebook

Tags: python, multithreading, unix, python-multithreading

I am currently using the **threading** function in python and got the following:

```
In [1]:
import threading
threading.activeCount()

Out[1]:
4
```

Now on my terminal, I use **lscpu** and learned there are 2 threads per core and I have access to 4 cores:

```
kitty@FelineFortress:~$ lscpu
Architecture:          x86_64
CPU op-mode(s):        32-bit, 64-bit
Byte Order:            Little Endian
CPU(s):                8
On-line CPU(s) list:   0-7
Thread(s) per core:    2
Core(s) per socket:    4
Socket(s):             1
NUMA node(s):          1
Vendor ID:             GenuineIntel
CPU family:            6
Model:                 60
Stepping:              3
CPU MHz:               800.000
BogoMIPS:              5786.45
Virtualization:        VT-x
L1d cache:             32K
L1i cache:             32K
L2 cache:              256K
L3 cache:              8192K
NUMA node0 CPU(s):     0-7
```

Hence, I should have a lot more than 4 threads to access. Is there a python function I can use to increase the number of cores I am using (with example) to get more than 4 threads? Or even something to type on the terminal when launching ipython notebook like below:

```
ipython notebook n_cores=3
```

Comment: There are unlimitted numbers of threads per core, but only 2 can be active at a time, you may want to do some reading on the differenes between physical cores and logical cores and threads and processes.
Also read up on the python GIL.
Also are you interested in the python way, or in the IPython way? (IPython has its own parellism library that works across multiple computers, as well as working on just one computer).

Comment: I am ok with either Python or IPython way. Python would be better as I am trying to create open source codes for people who might only use Python and note necessarily run IPython.

Comment: Be aware that `threading.activeCount()` is how many threads your program *has*, not any indication of what your system is capable of. It will increase if you create more threads.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can use [multiprocessing](https://docs.python.org/dev/library/multiprocessing.html) to allow Python to use multiple cores. Just one, big caveat: all the data you pass between Python sessions has to be picklable or passed via inheritance, and a new Python instance is spawned on Windows, while on Unix systems it can be forked over. This has notabled performance implications on a Windows system.

A basic [example](https://pymotw.com/2/multiprocessing/basics.html) using multiprocessing is as follows from "Python Module of the Week":

```
import multiprocessing

def worker():
    """worker function"""
    print 'Worker'
    return

if __name__ == '__main__':
    jobs = []
    for i in range(5):
        p = multiprocessing.Process(target=worker)
        jobs.append(p)
        p.start()
```

When executed, it outputs:

```
Worker
Worker
Worker
Worker
Worker
```

Multiprocessing allows you to do independent calculations on different cores, allowing CPU-bound tasks with little overhead to execute much more rapidly than a traditional process.

You should also realize that threading in Python does not improve performance. It exists for convenience (such as maintaining the responsiveness of a GUI during long calculations). The reason for this is these are not native threads due to Python's Global Interpreter Lock, or [GIL](https://wiki.python.org/moin/GlobalInterpreterLock).

### Update Feburary 2018

This is still very much applicable, and will be for the foreseeable future. The Cpython implementation uses the following [definition](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/f320be77ffb73e3b9e7fc98c37b8df3975d84b40/Include/object.h#L108) for reference counting:

```
typedef struct _object {
    _PyObject_HEAD_EXTRA
    Py_ssize_t ob_refcnt;
    struct _typeobject *ob_type;
} PyObject;
```

Notably, this is **not** thread-safe, so a global-interpreter lock must be implemented to allow only one thread of execution with Python objects to avoid data races leading to memory issues.

There are numerous tools to try to side-step the global interpreter lock, in addition to multiprocessing (which requires a complete copy of the interpreter on Windows, rather than a fork, making it very slow and unamenable to improving performance).

### Cython

Your simplest solution is Cython. Simply cdef a function, without any internal objects, and release the GIL with the `with nogil` keyword.

A simple example taken from the [documentation](https://cython.readthedocs.io/en/latest/src/userguide/parallelism.html), which shows you how to release, and temporarily re-enable the GIL:

```
from cython.parallel import prange

cdef int func(Py_ssize_t n):
    cdef Py_ssize_t i

    for i in prange(n, nogil=True):
        if i == 8:
            with gil:
                raise Exception()
        elif i == 4:
            break
        elif i == 2:
            return i
```

### Using a Different Interpreter

CPython has a GI, while Jython and IronPython do not. Be careful, as numerous C-libraries for high-performance computing may not work with IronPython or Jython (SciPy flirted with IronPython support, but dropped it long ago, and it will not work on a modern Python version).

### Using MPI4Py

MPI, or Message Passing Interface, is a high-performance interface for languages like C and C++. It allows efficient parallel computations, and MPI4Py creates bindings for MPI for Python. For efficiency, you should only use MPI4Py with NumPy arrays.

An example from their [documentation](http://mpi4py.scipy.org/docs/usrman/tutorial.html#running-python-scripts-with-mpi) is:

```
from mpi4py import MPI
import numpy

def matvec(comm, A, x):
    m = A.shape[0] # local rows
    p = comm.Get_size()
    xg = numpy.zeros(m*p, dtype='d')
    comm.Allgather([x,  MPI.DOUBLE],
                   [xg, MPI.DOUBLE])
    y = numpy.dot(A, xg)
    return y
```

Comment: Is there a way for me to access multiple threads for each core?

Comment: @Jack_The_Ripper, each multiprocessing instance can initiate threads, so yes, technically. But remember, these aren't native threads and so the threading guidelines aren't "fixed", they're guidelines.

But since each thread does not improve performance, unless you have a very good reason, the practical answer is no.

Using multiprocessing to boost performance by doing independent tasks separately, using multithreading to handle long, non-responsive tasks.

Comment: @AlexanderHuszagh as this is almost 2 years old, can I kindly ask you to check if this is still applicable. Thank you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48932854/using-ipython-for-parallel-computing-on-windows-10-local-host-personal-computer

Comment: @Victor, it still is. Python's threading and the GIL have made numerous improvements, but fundamentally, only one thread can execute at a time since reference counting is still not thread-safe to my knowledge. Your best bet, if you are willing to use Cython, is with the `no gil` statement. There are also many other tools. I'll update my statement.

Comment: @Victor Added numerous other tools to side-step the GIL, and an explanation of why the GIL is needed, without writing custom C extensions. Hopefully that helps.

Comment: @AlexanderHuszagh how can I pass parameters to the worker? Let's say in your example I'd like to pass i and print: "Worker {i}"

Comment: @Gavriel The docs still has an example for that here https://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.Process, and it's using the `args` keyword, which accepts a tuple of arguments to pass to the function. Please note if using a mutable type, the data will be a copy and so any changes you make will not be reflected in the type. If you need to share data, use SyncManager's collections: https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.managers.SyncManager.dict